# notepad is displaying txt file contents as weird symbols

Tags: windows, android, notepad, character-encoding, textfiles

I am writing integer values into file from kotlin (kotlin Int type) using something like this

```
var1BufferedWriter?.write(String.format("%d\n", intvar ) )   
var2BufferedWriter?.write(String.format("%08x\n", intvar ) )
```

`var1` above gets written into `textfile.txt` and `var2` into `textfile_hex.txt`. Both are saved into android phone sdcard memory. When I copy them into windows PC and open them in notepad, textfile.txt looks like this

[image]

while textfile_hex.txt looks like this:

[image]

If I open textfile.txt in a hex editor, I can see that all the data in the file is correct and what I expect to be there. Notepad++ shows everything correctly as well. The weird part is I have used this same app before the weekend to generate many other files similar to textfile.txt and they all looked normal in windows. Nothing has been changed in android or notepad settings.

Is this normal behaviour? Is this some kind of encoding issue? Why is notepad displaying some txt files correctly and not others?

Windows version:
Edition Windows 10 Pro
Version 22H2
OS build    19045.4046
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.19053.1000.0

Comment: Have you tried to modify encoding in Npp?

Comment: @Toto by Npp if you meant Notepad++, the file displays correctly here. My problem is only when opening it in windows' default notepad.exe program, which opens up when I double click on txt files

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood!

Comment: @Toto No worries, I will be happy to add more details if needed

Answer (score 2):

The file triggers a [false positive](http://web.archive.org/web/20040605124728if_/http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2004/03/24/95235.aspx) in Notepad's "Is Unicode" detection. (The issue even has [its own Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bush_hid_the_facts).)

- If your 'intvar' is always zero, then the file consists entirely of repeated `"0\n"`, which is stored as the bytes `{0x30, 0x0A}` in ASCII (and/or in UTF-8).

  ```
  "0"  "\n"  "0"  "\n"  "0"  "\n"  ...
  30   0A    30   0A    30   0A    ...
  ```
- You're seeing the Unicode character `"ਰ"` aka `"\u0A30"` aka [U+0A30](https://codepoints.net/U+0A30), which is **also** stored as the bytes `{0x30, 0x0A}` in UTF-16 LE.

  ```
  "ਰ"     "ਰ"     "ਰ"    ...
  30 0A   30 0A   30 0A  ...
  ```

Altering the output a little – e.g. adding some kind of "obviously ASCII" header or comment – would work around the problem.

You can also prefix the file's contents `"\xEF\xBB\xBF"` (or `"\uFEFF"`, whichever spelling Java/Kotlin prefers), which is the standard header to indicate that a file is UTF-8 and would cause Notepad (and all other text editors) to skip the auto-detection.

If Android supports it, you can have it write the file as *actual* UTF-16 (preferably with BOM included, so that it would bypass this part of the format detection).

(Your other files probably do not trigger the issue because they have at least one value ≥10, which "misaligns" the bytes so that they look a little more like ASCII and a little less like UTF-16 to the detection code.)

Comment: Could you provide a link to the issue's wikipedia page please?

Comment: Did you mean I have to add the 3 bytes `"\xEF\xBB\xBF"` to the beginning of the text file, then add whatever content I want to add normally, for this to not happen with notepad? Did I get this correctly?

Comment: Also, when you said `value ≥10` you meant my intvar has to be >=10 (0xA). Is that correct? If I look at the file containing hex equivalents, some of the values are `00000fda`, `00000ca1`, etc so some intvar's are definitely becoming larger than 10

Comment: Adding the 3 bytes `EF BB BF` will always force the file to be detected as UTF-8 without going through the less-reliable guessing code. It's not strictly what you *have to* add, it's one of the several proposed workarounds. Beyond that, the detection only considers the first X amount of bytes, not the entire file. (I think it was somewhere along the lines of 512 bytes? Not sure.)

Comment: @user13267 `EF BB BF` is the encoding of U+FEFF in UTF-8 and is called the [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) which acts like a header for Unicode files for differentiating charsets. See [There Ain't No Such Thing as Plain Text](https://blog.codinghorror.com/there-aint-no-such-thing-as-plain-text/)